# Unity - Particle Bounds do not match Particle Size

Tags: unity-game-engine, system, bounds, particles

Unity Version: 2017.3.1f1

I am currently having lots of trouble with my particle systems. I am writing some custom resizing code to scale some world elements. When I am trying to resize the particles size accordingly it looks like it is doing it wrong.
Now, after a while I found out that the resizing of the ParticleSystem.main.startSize is not the problem, but rather the bounds of the particles are wrong.

When in Scene View I can clearly see that the bounds are not matching up with the particle size. Imagine a simple block graphic of size 100x100 px being used as a particle. The actual size of the particle in the game is now 80x80 instead of 100x100 because there seems to be some kind of offset for the bounds.

[[image]

The material I created does not show this extra space. Using the hierarchy mode to scale the whole system does not work at all and the particle just becomes invisible.

Any pointers? I couldn't find any related issues on the net regarding this bounds problem.

Help much appreciated!